# Expose Vote History "Given To" data to each user

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, voting, moderator-tools

This (see screenshot below) is already part of the moderator dashboard.

Why not let a user view his own voting activity detail?

One loses track over time, and I would occasionally find it useful to see which users ***I*** have considered to be consistently noteworthy.

> [image: Vote Given To detail]

Answer (score 27):

It's part of the moderator tools so that moderators can investigate voting fraud when informed of it. There are some pretty significant restraints on who is shown, and those are likely to increase over time.

I don't think there's any particular value in encouraging people to revisit users they've voted for heavily in the past.

Answer (score 6):

> Why not let a user view his own voting activity detail?

Because it has no value to a user to show to whom he has given his votes. We vote on *posts*, not on *users*. Any tool that gives insight in to whom you have given your vote defeats that rule. For me, it is in the same category as 'follow user X since he has some useful answers'.

This view has a clear purpose, as [Shog9 explained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279603/245360): detecting and analyzing voting fraud. That is the only reason one should look at this statistics.

Comment: Also one usually remembers how they vote yes?

Comment: I hope so. But with 4000 votes you don't know the breakdown. And that isn't really important either.

Comment: I agree, and if there is a person that you are voting for frequently I guess I'd need to ask why? as it's the post not the person. I agree with your answer.