# Custom Mod Flagging for Suspicious Voting

Tags: discussion, support, flags, serial-voting

I am in the habit of raising custom mod flags when I see suspicious voting, perhaps voting rings.

When there is an ordinary, poor or even off topic question and answer with multiple upvotes within a short time frame I will create a custom mod flag so the accounts can be looked into.

Firstly, is this useful?

Second, is this the best way to go or is using the contact form better?

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222412/what-do-to-with-ultra-sophisticated-voting-ring

Comment: @ShadowWizard yeh thanks, I also wasn't so sure to what extent the mods could handle it, it's very clear now.. some kind of brain fuzz, I dunno must be the company I keep :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. That is totally okay to do and even encouraged. Moderators are here to make everyone play fair and to clean up garbage. It is the best to flag destructive behavior, so moderators can handle it.

The Contact Us goes directly to the SE team, so for stuff to be handled by a moderator they have to report it back, which is quite inefficient.

Comment: so mods can look at accounts for suspicious voting? My main confusion is who is able to see and do what.

Comment: Yes. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279602/245360

Comment: That is very helpful, I really did not realise that. A bit embarrassing after being around for a while.